# Get newly created Podio-PHP item id from PodioItem:Create

Tags: podio

I am trying to create new items in four apps apps via one form -- some the items will become app references.  For example, I first create an Entity item, then a Person item and relate the new Entity to the Person via an app reference field in the Person App.  Then create a Project and relate both the Person and the Entity to the Project.  This was successful until I upgraded to the latest Podio-PHP.  In the past, when newly created items were returning item_id as integer then I could pass that into the field as an app reference before the next item was created.

I've been trying to get the item_id as integer so I can do the same, but I keep getting null.  Anyway, given the way Podio now returns newly created items as objects, should I be trying this a different way?

```
$app_id = 1234567;

$fields = new PodioItemFieldCollection(array(
   ...I am defining external_id and values...
));

$item = new PodioItem(array(
  'app' => new PodioApp($app_id),
  'fields' => $fields,
));

if( $files ){
  $item->files = new PodioCollection($files);
};

$item->save();
$new_id = $item->item_id;
return $new_id;
```

$new_id is where I'm trying to store the integer so I can pass it along to the next item creation as an app reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really handled well in podio-php (it's been handled equally un-well since forever though). If you look at the `save` method you can see what's going on: https://github.com/podio/podio-php/blob/master/models/PodioItem.php#L58-L72

```
public function save($options = array()) {
  $json_attributes = $this->as_json_without_readonly_fields();

  if ($this->id) {
    return self::update($this->id, $json_attributes, $options);
  }
  else {
    if ($this->app && $this->app->id) {
      return self::create($this->app->id, $json_attributes, $options);
    }
    else {
      throw new PodioMissingRelationshipError('{"error_description":"Item is missing relationship to app"}', null, null);
    }
  }
}
```

`save()` doesn't assign the new item_id to the object itself. This is a bug and it would be good if you created an issue at https://github.com/podio/podio-php/issues so it can be fixed.

For now you can see that `save()` returns the same as the static `create` method. So your last three lines needs to be replaced with:

```
$new_item_placeholder = $item->save();
$item->item_id = $new_item_placeholder->item_id;
return $item->item_id;
```